# ¿Cómo puedo agregarle fuentes a mi página web?

Tags: html, css

Llevo dias buscando una manera de como poner fuentes en mi página web pero en todos los tutoriales que veo, de la manera en que lo hacen, no me funciona de ninguna manera. Soy un principiante de esto de las páginas web y agradeceria la ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] ya realizar el [tour]. Tal como está redactada tu pregunta, se basa en opiniones. Existen diversas formas de *añadir* fuentes a una página web, cada una con sus pro y sus contras. Si pudieras mostrar el código `html` de cómo estás intentando añadir las fuentes, tal vez tu pregunta sería más concreta. Saludos

Comment: se hace con font-family: "fuente"; para buscar una fuente puedes ir a https://fonts.google.com/ y poner la que más te gusta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con CSS, con `@font-face`

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "Mi fuente";
    src:url("mi fuente.ttf");
}
```

En `font-family` le puedes poner el nombre que quieras, sinceramente

Para usar tu fuente:

```css
selector {
    font-family:"miFuente";
}
```

Puedes poderle de `font-family` el nombre que le pusiste a la fuente anteriormente, si quieres usar fuentes predeterminadas `@font-face` no es necesario

```css
body, html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Creo que la respuesta está incompleta, ya que no especifica la circunstancia, esto funciona cuando has concatenado fuentes y las agregas al proyecto, pero @Sidney Silva no aclara si ya realizó ese paso, esta respueta podría confundir a principiantes que buscan información, y si no se explica el porque de cada linea, generaría más frustración.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una es con css:

```
html {
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
}
```

Si quieres usar otras fuentes tienes que ir a https://fonts.google.com/, elegir la fuente y copiar el codigo html (Ejemplo:``` <`` link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"``> ```) y en el css poner `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`.

Otra forma es poniendo en el css el codigo que te dirá google fonts (Ejemplo: @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');) y en el css poner `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;`. Cada fuente tiene un codigo diferente. Espero que te funcione.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!